# How to prompt 3DS Authentication on stripe for subscription on nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm very new to nodejs and trying out with Stripe Node.JS subscription. It was okay for the subscription without the 3ds authentication. But if there is a requires_action for the 3ds authentication then my application will be failed to proceed.

I did read the documentation and try for the confirmcardpayment method but failed to build my application on the server. I follow a few suggestion on stackoverflow but nothing had work for me to prompt or redirect the user if there was 3ds authentication needed.

As i know there should be a return_url if there was require for authentication when subscription, but i did try and it just return "use_stripe_sdk" but does not contain any url. Is there any suggestion for my to enchance for my code?

Here are my server code :

```
import { UnprocessableEntityException } from '@exceptions/http-exception';
import { Member } from '@interfaces/member.interface';
import { config } from '@providers/config.provider';
import { Logger } from '@providers/logger.provider';
import { generateNumericID } from '@providers/nanoid.provider';
import { stripe } from '@providers/stripe.provider';
import { repositories } from '@repositories/index.repository';
import { dayjs } from '@utils/dayjs.util';

export class SubscriptionService {
  private readonly logger = Logger('SubscriptionService');

  async susbcribe(params: {
    member: Member;
    branch: string;
    package: string;
    phone: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    stripePriceID: string;
  }) {
    const {
      member,
      branch,
      package: subscriptionPackage,
      email,
      phone,
      name,
      stripePriceID,
    } = params;

    const paymentMethods = await stripe.paymentMethods.list({
      type: 'card',
      customer: member.stripeCustomerID,
    });

    if (paymentMethods.data.length === 0) {
      throw new UnprocessableEntityException('Payment Method Missing');
    }

    const formattedNRICNumber = member.ic.replace(/-/g, '');

    const isNewMember = member.memberType === 'recurring' && !member.oneOffPaymentPaidAt;

    const payment = await repositories.payment.create({
      data: {
        branch,
        name,
        type: 'renew',
        amount: 70,
        marking: 0,
        phone,
        photo: Buffer.from(''),
        interest_branch: branch,
        order_id: Number(generateNumericID(7)),
        email: email || '',
        onlineprocess: 0,
        payment_id: '',
        ic_number: formattedNRICNumber,
        package: 'recurring',
        status: 'Pending',
        date: dayjs().toDate(),
      },
    });

    if (isNewMember) {
      this.logger.info('New Member detected, charging an additional RM 70');

      await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: 7000,
        currency: 'MYR',
        customer: member.stripeCustomerID,
        payment_method: paymentMethods.data[0].id,
        metadata: {
          NRIC: formattedNRICNumber,
          type: 'FIRST_TIME',
        },
        confirm: true,
        confirmation_method: 'manual',
        use_stripe_sdk: true,
      });
    }

    const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
      customer: member.stripeCustomerID,
      items: [
        {
          price: config.STRIPE_PRICE_ID,
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      metadata: {
        memberID: member.no,
        nric: member.ic,
        paymentID: payment.id,
      },
    });
    const invoice = await stripe.invoices.retrieve(subscription.latest_invoice as string);
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(invoice.payment_intent as string);
    
    if (paymentIntent.status === 'requires_action' && paymentIntent.next_action?.type === 'use_stripe_sdk') {
      // The payment intent requires 3D Secure authentication
      const authenticationUrl = paymentIntent.next_action.use_stripe_sdk.redirect_to_url.url;
  
      // Redirect the user to the authentication URL for 3D Secure authentication
      // For example, in an Express.js app, you can use res.redirect(authenticationUrl) to redirect the user
      // You may need to pass the authenticationUrl to the front-end and handle the redirect there
      return {
        requiresAction: true,
        authenticationUrl,
      };
    }
  

    return subscription;
  }
}
```